# Nifi ExecuteGroovyScript - class already loaded in another classloader

Tags: java, groovy, bigdata, apache-nifi

**I get a flowfile with ExecuteGroovyScript processor with some custom code in it.
and it work well :**

[image]

but if I stop it and change the code in i get this **error:**

[image]

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library
>   /data/nifi_flow/dec-enr/pseudo/lib/libpseudojni.so already loaded in
>   another classloader: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library
>   /data/nifi_flow/dec-enr/pseudo/lib/libpseudojni.so already loaded in
>   another classloader java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library
>   /data/nifi_flow/dec-enr/pseudo/lib/libpseudojni.so already loaded in
>   another classloader
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1907)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
>           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
>           at fr.cnam.p7.pseudo.jni.PseudoJNI.(PseudoJNI.java:6)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray$1.run(CallSiteArray.java:68)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray$1.run(CallSiteArray.java:65)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallStaticSite(CallSiteArray.java:65)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:162)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
>           at Scriptffffffffc26c8c01.run(Scriptffffffffc26c8c01.groovy:26)
>           at org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript.onTrigger(ExecuteGroovyScript.java:438)
>           at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
>           at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1122)
>           at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:147)
>           at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
>           at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:128)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

After restarting nifi the processor is back to normal and work well again.

Comment: Could you share your script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to the stacktrace

```
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122) 
at fr.cnam.p7.pseudo.jni.PseudoJNI.(PseudoJNI.java:6) 
at Scriptffffffffc26c8c01.run(Scriptffffffffc26c8c01.groovy:26)
```

the class (PseudoJNI) you are loading from script tries to load native library

each time you change the groovy script or other parameters the new classloader used  because `@Grab` or added classpath could be used for your script.

calling `System.loadLibrary()` from the second classloader triggers an error. you could try to put the library that contains PseudoJNI class into nifi/lib directory.